# Prove that$\frac{x+2-\sqrt{3}}{1+(\sqrt{3}-2)x}$=$\frac{1-{x^2}}{2x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving

Well, I was trying to find $\tan40$ in terms of $\tan25$=x.

So, I expanded 40 as 25+15 and got the value of $\tan40$ in terms of $x$ as $\frac{x+2-\sqrt{3}}{1+(\sqrt{3}-2)x}$.

Now, I solved $\tan40$ alternatively as

$$\frac{\tan155-\tan115}{1+\tan155\tan115}= \frac{\tan(180-25)-tan(90+25)}{1+\tan(180-25)tan(90+25)}= \frac{-\tan25+\cot25}{1+\tan25{\cot25}}=\frac{1}{2}(-x+\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1-{x^2}}{2x}$$

But, we should have same solution from both the approaches.

Therefore, $\frac{x+2-\sqrt{3}}{1+(\sqrt{3}-2)x}$ must be equals to $\frac{1-{x^2}}{2x}$. But I'm unable to prove it by algebra. So, can you kindly help me?

Comment: @Claude-Leibovici I think everything is written correctly

Comment: Easier $\tan 40=\cot(90-40)=\cot(2\cdot 25)$.

Comment: I do not really see the purpose of this question. If you have shown by algebraic calculations that $A=\tan 40=B$ wouldn't it mean that you have proved $A=B$ by algebra?

Comment: @A.G. forget the details of the question and just prove the equality without trigonometry as I've used. I just added the details so that my question is not closed or put on hold.

Comment: If you want to get rid of trigonometry completely then you have to define $x$ without $\tan$. It looks as unnecessary artificial complification though.

Answer (score 1):

On rearrange we have

$$2+\sqrt3=\dfrac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}=\cdots=\tan(3\cdot25^\circ)$$

Now $$\tan(75^\circ)=\tan(45^\circ+30^\circ)=?$$

Comment: Perfect and neat! +1. Could you give reason on how it _occured_ to you? Did you just happen to try the formula of $Tan(3x)$?

Comment: @blackpen, When I saw the cubic in the expression, $$\tan3x$$ formula occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

When $\frac{1-x^2}{2x}$ is equated to $\frac{x+2−\sqrt{3}}{1+(\sqrt{3}-2)x}$, it gives rise to: $$x^3-3(\sqrt{3}+2)x^2-3x+(\sqrt{3}+2)=0$$

Wolfram gives three roots:$$x≈-0.700208,\,\,\,x≈0.466308,\,\,\,x≈11.4301$$
Also, note that, $\tan{25}≈0.4663076...$

It is not a satisfying "exact" proof, but something to get a sense of things.